# JavaScript: Error from converting user inputed image to base64

Tags: javascript, image

Trying to store user image to server. Very new to this, so I just started looking around and I found the following code:

```
function getBase64Image( imgElem ) {

    let canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;

    let ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);

    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL( 'image/png' );
    return dataURL.replace( /^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '' );

}
```

I'm using this function to store a user inputed image on my local server, but I get the following error:

> factories.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type
>   '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or
>   ImageBitmap)'getBase64Image @ factories.js:1SubmitRecipe @
>   recipe-submission.js:1onclick @ submitrecipe:43

I am grabbing the image with an input tag that has `type` set to `file`. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<label>Image</label>
<span class='err-message' id='image-err'></span></br>
<input type="file" id='image'>
```

**JS**

```
function SubmitRecipe() {

    //sets the recipe object and its keys
    let recipe = { alias: null, description: null, category: null, instructions: null, image: null };

    let img = document.getElementById( 'image' );
    recipe.image = JSON.stringify( getBase64Image( img ) );

}
```

I believe the problem has to do with the fact that the element `image` is an `HTMLInputElement`, and that isn't what `drawImage` expects. I just have no idea how to solve it.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you place canvas element in your html??

Comment: If you have Are you sure this function called on succesfull loading of image?? I mean onload event

Comment: @kernallora Isn't that what `let canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );` is doing? And the error is coming from `ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);`, so I believe the function is being called.

Comment: The problem is that your imgElem isn't actually an image element, but is instead an input element - one that can accept images. So while the data ultimately held by the element is compatible with `.drawImage`, the element itself is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the FileReader object to do this. The really neat thing is it can even give us the data as a data URL in the first place - this means we dont convert/recompress images in the process. A jpg wont be enlarged by saving as a png, nor will a png lose detail by conversion to a jpg.
Since we're no longer using the canvas to create the URL, we no longer have control over the precise mime-type. As such, we may have a jpg,png or jpeg file - this just means adding `|jpeg` to the regex so we replace instances of it too.

You can also listen to the `change` event of the file input. Doing so will allow you to check the size and type of file to ensure they are acceptable. (Someone could select a 100MB text file using the file input)

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function newEl(tagName){return document.createElement(tagName)}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onBtnClicked, false);
}

function onBtnClicked(evt)
{
 let imgInput = byId('imageInput');
 let chosenFile = imgInput.files[0];
 let fr = new FileReader();
 fr.onload = function(evt)
    {
                    var img = newEl('img');
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                    img.src = this.result;
      
     var dataURL = this.result.replace( /^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, '' );
     let recipe = { alias: null, description: null, category: null, instructions: null, image: JSON.stringify(dataURL) };
     console.log(recipe);
    };
 fr.readAsDataURL(chosenFile);
}
```

```html
<label>Image</label>
 <span class='err-message' id='image-err'></span></br>
 <input type="file" id='imageInput'>
 <button id='goBtn'>GO</button>
```

Comment: This works. Out of curiosity, how would I display this image back onto the DOM? I.e. put it as the source of an image tag?

Comment: Funnily enough, that's actually exactly what you do! I've updated my demo to show a preview of the image. Notice that I'm doing it to the raw result of the filereader, _without_ changing the string with the regex or json-ing. The whole idea of base64 of the source is that it's transmittable (submittable) text already, as-is. So, yuo may just set the image attribute of your recipe to the base64 result and then `json.stringify` the whole thing instead of changing the image source and `json.stringify`ing it before storing to the image attribute of the recipe object.

Comment: I.e - `fr.onload = function(evt){let recipe = { alias: null, description: null, category: null, instructions: null, image: this.result }; console.log(recipe);}`

Comment: Pefrect! So if I were to store this on the back end, I would use `JSON.stringify()`, and then when I returned it to the front end, I would just use `JSON.parse()` and then display it in an image tag?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'd consider doing. Here's another answer you may find helpfu - note inside the `onPostOkay` function that an image is created and has its source set with a base64 string.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709188/render-an-image-binary-data-into-a-img-or-canvas-tag/39711448#39711448

Answer (score 0):

The question is you couldn't get file path pass through input in the chrome、fireFox,IE8 can get it when choosed file.