# turn image binary data into img tag

Tags: javascript, html

When i do a post request to a route i have

```
/generate/image
```

i get something like: var file =

```
����JFIF��C��C��� ��    
�����+�}Yϭ�F39M>���������>���;��ˋ��uXʽ�w�ڤx\-[2g��k�S���H���m
[�V?[_W����#��v��}6�[��F�F�%����n�...
```

in the client i do:

```
var blob = new Blob([file], {type: 'image/png'});
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
   $('#result').attr('src', e.target.result);
};

reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

but i get a corrupt image

what can i do?

EDIT:
if i do

```
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(file);
```

i get:

```
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
```

Comment: base64 encode it and use a [data uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. `attr` is a jQuery function, not a JavaScript function.

Comment: Xufox sorry i have jquery included and i did changed getElementById, it was a typo

Comment: Still shouldn't be able call `attr()` on a Javascript object. Besides, you are already using jQuery, why not just use `$('#result').attr(...)`

Comment: i corrected that on the question now.

Comment: still, if i do a btoa to the binary data i get 
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26603875/1887101

Comment: I tried escape and encodeURIComponent but the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your backend you can do following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(path to image from you file, 'base64', function(err, buf){
      /* Here you can send your base64 image data to client. Your base64 data is in buf. 
      I am using socket. You can just send. Read more about readFile function*/
      socket.emit('image upload', { image: true, buffer: buf });
});
```

As my client receives data from socket, I call a function:

```
socket.on('image upload', function(data){
                displayImage(data);
            });

var displayImage = function(data){
                var URL = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+data.buffer;
                document.querySelector('#img-id').src = URL;
            };
```

The image will then be showed in img tag.
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use base64 and wast bandwidth + CPU 
Send the image binary as is and handle them correctly with Ajax. 
You should not get the result as a string. set xhr responseType to blob or use fetch's blob method.

```
fetch("/generate/image").then(res => res.blob())
```

When you have the blob don't use the file reader to turn it to a url.

Use URL.createObjectURL(blob)